# Comparing two files field by field in Linux

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to compare two files (separted by comma and space) using 3 fields (field 1,2, 5 from file1 and 1,2,5 from file2) if the two files match i want the whole record of file2 concatenated with the last filed of file1 using awk. for example
file1:

```
1, 4, abebe, kebede, 25, 101, 42
1, 4, abebe, debebe, 42, 201, 47
1, 4, abebech, kebede, 17, 33, 57
```

file2:

```
1, 4, abebe, kebede, 25, 101, 42
1, 4, Tesse, debo, 25, 101, 42
1, 4, derartu, tulu, 25, 101, 42
```

output:

```
42, 1, 4, abebe, kebede, 25, 101, 42
47, 1, 4, Tesse, debo, 25, 101, 42
57, 1, 4, derartu, tulu, 25, 101, 42
```

I am new for linux.... any help is apprciated

Comment: the files are file1: 1, 4, abebe, kebede, 25, 101, 42 (rec1) 1, 4, abebe, debebe, 42, 201, 47(rec2) 1, 4, abebech, kebede, 17, 33, 42 (rec3) file2: 1, 4, abebe, kebede, 25, 101, 42 (rec1) 1, 4, Tesse, debo, 25, 101, 42(rec2) 1, 4, derartu, tulu, 25, 101, 42(rec3)

Comment: Fields 1, 2 and 5 of record 1 in file 1 match *all* the records in file 2.

Comment: Your output does not match the problem description.   All of the records in file 2 match the fields 1,4,25 of the first record in file1, so all the lines of your output should begin with 42.  Do you actually care about field 4 instead of field 5?

Answer (score 1):

My first reading of the problem lends itself to this solution:

```
awk '{getline t < "file2"; split( t, a );
    if( a[1]a[2]a[5] == $1$2$5) print $NF",", t}' file1
```

But it appears that the question is actually: 'Given `file1` in which we know that any record in which fields 1, 2, and 4 are the same the final field is also the same, find all lines in `file2` with corresponding fields 1, 2, and 4 and output that line with the final field from `file1` prepended.  In which case the solution given by Dennis works.

Comment: That does a line for line comparison, however the OP didn't specify whether the lines from the two files corresponded or whether one file had more lines than the other.

Comment: @Dennis, indeed, the question specification is vague.

Comment: the number of records in the files is different

Comment: This works perfectly for line by line comparison. But what if I want to search each record of the first file in the second file and print  it if i get a match?

Answer (score 1):

Since fields 1, 2 and 5 of record 1 in file 1 match *all* the records in file 2 I have listed the files as arguments in the opposite order in order to get the output you want.

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS = ", "} NR == FNR {a[$1, $2, $5] = $NF; next} $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $5 in a {print a[$1, $2, $5], $0}' file2 file1
```

The `NR == FNR` block forms a loop that reads the file which appears first in the argument list into an array. When the record number (`NR`) and the file record number (`FNR`) are no longer equal, processing continues to the file which is named as the second argument.

There, the array is checked to see if the fields from the two files match. If so, the corresponding saved field and the current record are output.

Comment: I need the program to compare line by line . line one from file1 with the corresponding line from file2. The number of records in the two files are different

Comment: If the number of lines in the files are different, what do you mean by "the corresponding line"?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: the line that has `$1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $5 in a`. In other words, fields 1, 2 and 5 match between the two files regardless of the number of records in each file. Their relative or absolute order is unimportant (they are unsorted).

Comment: @WilliamPurse:it will read line by line from the two files and compare the two lines

Comment: @TesseM: It doesn't read from the two files in lockstep, though. It reads all of one file then all of the other.

Comment: I have two questions . First print a[$1, $2, $5] is printing nothing, why is that? the second one is , what if i want to compare the files based on different record numbers (1, 2, 3 from file1 and 4,5,6 from file2 , assume they have the same data type) and prepend  field 7 from file1 on the output (I edited on my original question)

Comment: @TesseM: It works fine for me. I don't know why it's not printing anything for you. This should work to handle the different fields: `awk 'BEGIN {OFS = ", "} NR == FNR {a[$1, $2, $3] = $7; next} $4 SUBSEP $5 SUBSEP $6 in a {print a[$4, $5, $6], $0}' file2 file1`

Comment: @Dennis it still print nothing may be because I am trying a[$1, $2, $3]?what does $7 stands for?. What I need is the whole record of file to together with $7 of file1 to be displayed. Sorry if i sound silly